# python авторизация request

Tags: python, requests, urllib

Мне нужно сделать авторизацию на сайт . Если я введу какой-либо верный или неверный пароль, то программа вернет результат `<response 200>`. Может я не туда обращаюсь для авторизации?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно post запросом запросить авторизацию на сайте!

```
r = requests.post('<url>', data = {'username':'username', 'password': 'password'...})
```

посмотреть,  что вернул ответ можно через r.json() сам статус код можешь вернуть через r.status_code

Comment: Спасибо!Однако выдает error 403(forbidden)